# How do I run two separate Django sites based on a subdomain?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have two Django sites. One is a staging site and the other is production. I want the staging site to be visible at `beta.ialexander.io` and the production one at `ialexander.io`. I'm using `mod_wsgi` with Apache. Here are the two `.conf` files:

`ialexander.conf`:

```
# WSGI Stuff
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/Ullmannite

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # WSGI Stuff
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Ullmannite/Ullmannite/wsgi.py

  # Identification
  ServerName ialexander.io 
  ServerAdmin Alexander2475914@gmail.com

  # Public files
  Alias /assets /var/www/Ullmannite/public

  # Logs
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/iAlexander-Error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/iAlexander-Access.log combined

  # Access
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/Ullmannite/public"

  <Directory "/var/www/Ullmannite/Ullmannite">
    <Files "wsgi.py">
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/var/www/Ullmannite/public">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`000-ialexander-staging.conf`:

```
# WSGI Stuff
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/Ullmannite-Staging

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # WSGI Stuff
  WSGIScriptAlias /beta /var/www/Ullmannite-Staging/Ullmannite/wsgi.py

  # Identification
  ServerName ialexander.io
  ServerAdmin Alexander2475914@gmail.com

  # Public files
  Alias /assets /var/www/Ullmannite-Staging/public

  # Logs
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/iAlexander-Staging-Error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/iAlexander-Staging-Access.log combined

  # Access
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/Ullmannite-Staging/public"

  <Directory "/var/www/Ullmannite-Staging/Ullmannite">
    <Files "wsgi.py">
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/var/www/Ullmannite-Staging/public">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've been struggling with this for weeks now. Originally in `000-ialexander-staging.conf` I had `WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Ullmannite-Staging/Ullmannite/wsgi.py` and `ServerName beta.ialexander.io`, but that didn't give me what I need. I don't remember exactly what happened because this was around two weeks ago.

Currently I have `000-ialexander-staging.conf` disabled because it breaks the other one (`ialexander.conf`). However, when I have `000-ialexander-staging.conf` enabled and I visit `http://ialexander.io/beta` I see the production site.

I know there's a glitch where you have to have the sites which have `WSGIScriptAlias` values in order. If I have the first one where `WSGIScriptAlias` is set to `/` before the second one it'll send that one, first. That's the reason I've named `000-ialexander-staging.conf` with the `000-` prefix. I wanted to make sure Apache is reading that one first, because it's the one that has a `WSGIScriptAlias` value of `/beta`.

Why are these things happening and how can I get the production site to return at `ialexander.io` but the staging one at `beta.ialexander.io`?

Comment: I am more of an nginx guy, but when you were doing `WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Ullmannite-Staging/Ullmannite/wsgi.py` and `ServerName beta.ialexander.io` you were doing it right. What happend when you did that is the real issue. So do this and post what happens after this.

Comment: When I do that it `ialexander.io` behaves normally, but when I visit `beta.alexander.io` it returns a different website. It returns a site I made about Italy for school. If you go to http://beta.ialexander.io/ you can see how these `.conf` files are behaving. Here's the Gist: https://gist.github.com/Arcrammer/256ad69a5ccc076fe657de505b83fa8a

Answer (score 0):

here is what I do in one `httpd.conf` file for Windows:

*note:

1. NO `WSGIPythonPath` outside `VirtualHost`s - If it exists, two `VirtualHost`s cannot have different python-django configurations
2. there are separated two django projects
3. domains we want to separate are `(www.)ialexander.io` and `beta.ialexander.io`
4. No virtualenv used. (I am not sure whether this is going to be issue...)

   ```
   # for the public site
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/Ullmannite/public"
   ServerName ialexander.io 
   ServerAlias www.ialexander.io 

   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Ullmannite/Ullmannite/wsgi.py
   # ...other things the same...

   </VirtualHost>

   # for the staging site
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/Ullmannite-Staging/public"
   ServerName beta.ialexander.io 

   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Ullmannite-Staging/Ullmannite/wsgi.py
   # ...other things the same...

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Comment: When I have those `WSGIPythonPath`s in the `VirtualHost`s I get the error `AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ialexander.conf:
WSGIPythonPath cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section`. What is a virtualenv? I keep hearing about this thing and I've tried to install it once but I failed. Other than that the `.conf` you posted is what I already have.

Comment: Oh yes, `WSGIPythonPath` cannot be in the `VirtualHost`; that's why I never used this in config. and what I want to address is that different `ServerName`s should be used...  these are the same in your conf if you wrote not mistakenly.

Comment: Also `virtualenv` is an independent python environment. If you really don't know what it is, [this instruction](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) may help.